# GDAL in Java fails on ReadRaster()

Tags: raster, gdal, java

To summarize, trying to read a raster keeps giving me an UnsatisfiedLinkError that makes sense, but looking into the compiled GDAL jar, I don't know how to fix.

```
gdal.AllRegister();
TheFile = gdal.Open(filepath);

double[] attributes = TheFile.GetGeoTransform();
extent = new int[] {TheFile.GetRasterXSize(), TheFile.GetRasterYSize()};
pixel_size = new double[] {attributes[1], attributes[5]};
corner = new double[] {attributes[0], attributes[3]};

Band TheBand = TheFile.GetRasterBand(1);
TheData = new double[extent[0]][extent[1]];
for(int y = 0; y < extent[1]; y++) {
    TheBand.ReadRaster(0, y, extent[0], 1, TheData[y]);
}
```

So the preceding code should just open and load the raster (specifically a tiff), line by line, into an array. This however fails at ReadRaster() with the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.gdalconst.gdalconstJNI.DMD_LONGNAME_get()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.gdal.gdalconst.gdalconstJNI.DMD_LONGNAME_get(Native Method)
    at org.gdal.gdalconst.gdalconstConstants.<clinit>(gdalconstConstants.java:75)
```

Now I notice that the problem is the method called `DMD_LONGNAME_get()` can't be found. Looking into the gdalconstJNI.java in the GDAL jar file I see there is a similar but slightly differently named method called `GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME_get()`. So I understand the unsatisfied link error, but why is it named differently and how do I fix it?

I used the GDAL wrapper from [here](http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/), in particular the latest MSVC2010 Win64 stable release (as of now: release-1600-x64-gdal-1-10) and followed all the proper installation instructions, updating my 2010 Visual C++ Redistributable x64 (and x86 for good measure), running the bat file, creating all the environment paths, adding the -Djava.library.path to the project's VM options, making sure everything's compatible with 64-bit Win7, so I don't think there's a problem there.

Is this just a GDAL badly written to Java issue? (I mean it seems that way with the mismatched naming issue). Is there a previous release version I should go with? If so, which version? as I don't want to have to try it one by one.

**UPDATE** Just tried with the oldest GDAL version in the previously mentioned site with compiled GDAL wrappers (gdal-1-7-3), in which the `DMD_LONGNAME_get()` exists. However now I get the same error but instead the method missing is now `GARIO_PENDING_get()I` which I don't find any version of it in gdalconstJNI.java. Unless I get a response I suppose I'll just have to keep trying different versions and see if there is a sweet spot, but this seems clumsy/time-consuming so hopefully someone has run into this before.